# UITableView first section hidden by viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have a UITableView which is a grouped table view. I am trying to add an image as the header of the table view (and only for the first section). The problem I'm having is that the image is covering the first section of the tableview.

Here's the code:

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 80)];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.eventsforacausesf.com/uploads/8/7/3/0/8730216/3416277_orig.jpg"]];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, headerView.frame.size.width, headerView.frame.size.height)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [headerView addSubview:imageView];

    if (section == 0) {
        return headerView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

For example, in the image below, the first section of the tableview is hidden behind the image. I need to move that section below the image.

[image: Description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're setting with that data source method is a header for a particular section of the table view, but it sounds to me like what you want is to set the `tableViewHeader` of the table view itself.  Set your table view's `tableViewHeader` property to your header view instead of returning the header view as a section header.  Then you'll get the standard iOS header vs. content layout.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` to return the height of the image view.

Comment: That worked. The other issue I noticed now, is that when I implement `tableView: viewForHeaderInSection`, the `tableView: titleForHeaderInSection` for the section is not displayed for some reason

Comment: If you return a view != nil then the titleForHeader… is not called. But you can call it from inside viewForHeader… and use the string there.